# Highlight cells based on cell content with Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

This is for an Microsoft Excel VBA macro. What it is supposed to do, for every row, when "Late" is entered into column C, to highlight the cell 2 spaces to the left and Range of cells 3 spaces to the right through 43. So example is C4 contains "Late", highlight A4 and F4:AW4. Same goes for the word "Hold" just a different color.

```
Private Sub Highlight_Condition(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim cell As Range
Dim i As Long
With ActiveSheet
  lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1
     If .Range("C" & i).Value = "LATE" Then
        Debug.Print "Checking Row: " & i
        .Range("A" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 39
        .Range("F" & i & ":AW" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 39
     ElseIf .Range("C" & i).Value = "HOLD" Then
        .Range("A" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 43
        .Range("F" & i & ":AW" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 43
     Else
        .Range("A" & i & ":AW" & i).ClearContents
        .Range("F" & i & ":AW" & i).ClearContents

     End If
  Next i
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you aware that criteria like `If cell.Value = "LATE" Then` are case sensitive? Your narrative describes `C4 contains "Late"` and `"Late" <> "LATE"` and *contains* is not necessarily the same as the entire cell value.

Comment: Would using wildcards take care of this? If cell.Value = "*LATE*" Then

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you...

```
Private Sub Highlight_Condition(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim cell As Range
Dim i As Long
With ActiveSheet
lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
Application.EnableEvents = False
For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1
 If .Range("C" & i).Value = "LATE" Then
    Debug.Print "Checking Row: " & i
    .Range("A" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 39
    .Range("F" & i & ":AW" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 39
 ElseIf .Range("C" & i).Value = "HOLD" Then
    .Range("A" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 43
    .Range("F" & i & ":AW" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 43
 Else
    .Range("A" & i & ":AW" & i).ClearContents
    .Range("F" & i & ":AW" & i).ClearContents

 End If
Next i
Application.EnableEvents = True
End With
End Sub
```

Tested and seems to work fine for me :)

Comment: Problem with this is blows away all formatting, and I'd wanted to run it in the worksheet private code. I updated the original but won't take.

Comment: Just to clarify, it blows all formatting away when ran. I want it to remove the formatting added by this code as soon as the value in column C is deleted.    `.Range("A" & i & ":AW" & i).ClearContents` and `.Range("F" & i & ":AW" & i).ClearContents` i believe should work

Comment: @TomaszKozuch If you want it removed when deleted you'll have to add this code into the Worksheet's `Worksheet_Change` code segment

Comment: So in other words `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`

Comment: @TomaszKozuch Yes, exactly

Answer (score 0):

> ... C4 **contains** "Late" ... *(emphasis mine)*

This seems to indicate that *Late* may be part of a longer string. I will code to that effect.

Conditional formatting rules are a quick method of achieving your cell highlighting and respond as soon as values in column C change without rerunning the sub procedure (unless more values are added below the *lastRow*).

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()
    Const TEST_COLUMN As String = "D"
    Dim lastRow As Long, sSheetName As String

    sSheetName = ActiveSheet.Name

    With Worksheets(sSheetName)
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, TEST_COLUMN).End(xlUp).Row
        With .Range("A4:A" & lastRow & ", F4:AW" & lastRow)
            .FormatConditions.Delete
            .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=isnumber(search(""late"", $c4))"
            .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).Interior.ColorIndex = 39
            .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=isnumber(search(""hold"", $c4))"
            .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).Interior.ColorIndex = 43
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Great! I wanted to run this in the worksheet and not as a module. So i added a few extra lines and ByVal Target As Range to fire everytime a change is made in the range but it doesn't seem to work. Am i missing something?

```
Private Sub Highlight_Condition(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim cell As Range
Dim i As Long
With ActiveSheet
  LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1
     If .Range("C" & i).Value = "LATE" Then
        Debug.Print "Checking Row: " & i
        .Range("A" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 39
        .Range("F" & i & ":AW" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 39
     ElseIf .Range("C" & i).Value = "HOLD" Then
        .Range("A" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 43
        .Range("F" & i & ":AW" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 43
     Else
        .Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
     End If
  Next i
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Please don't post code in the responses area. Edit your original question to include it or post a new question with the code.

Comment: btw, you shouldn't be using *ActiveSheet* in a worksheet's private code sheet if you expect reliable results.